# Redis using as disk persistance with RDB and AOF file

Tags: redis

We are using redis server in production with 6 GB data size, Initially 
we thought redis can be used as memory cache only, If it restarts then we can repopulate from the persistants data store with minimal downtime.

Now we realized that re-population of data from persistence store is not a good idea at all, It is causing major service downtime.

We want to evaluate redis persistant option by using RDB and AOF combination.We tried taking RDB snapshot once in a hour and committing to the AOF file with one second interval in test environments. AOF file is growing too big in test environment only. We tried to analyze the AOF file content and noticed that lot of keys we don't want to persist to the disk, We need them only in redis memory.

Is there any way to stop logging certain type of keys (block list keys) while logging to the AOF file

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Redis does not provide a way to exclude certain types of keys from persistency. If you need some keys to persist to disk and others not to, you should use two independent Redis instances - one for each type and configure their persistency settings approriately. Divide and conquer.

Note: it is possible, however, to control what gets persisted in AOF inside the context if a Lua script - see the ["Selective replication of commands" section of `EVAL`'s documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval#selective-replication-of-commands). That said, besides the consistency risks, it would be too much of a hassle to use this approach for what you need imo.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will evaluate it once. 
It would be great if you can clarify few more things. 
1) Do I need to use replica for enabling this option? 
2) How will it affects other clients who access the redis-server during that point of time?
3) Is it session/client wise or it applies for all other sessions/clients

Comment: Assuming you mean the "Note", 1) no, 2) like any command, the script will block until it completes, 3) this is per script invocation